# YouTube API - simultaneous viewers for live streams and number of chat messages in live streams

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, live-streaming

I'm looking for two metrics in YouTube API: `simultaneous viewers for live streams` and `number of chat messages in live streams`, but I couldn't find it.

Also, I found this option https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos, specifically this one `liveStreamingDetails.concurrentViewers`, however, it's not clear if I can only get data during the video live stream.

Any help?